# Trying to parse a JSON result from Rotten Tomatoes API

Tags: android, json, rotten-tomatoes

I'm succeeding in getting the movie's title and year, but somehow not the synopsis. as far as I understand the object's shape they should be reachable in the same way:

```
JSONObject resultOBJ = new JSONObject(result);
Log.v("hhhh",resultOBJ.toString());
JSONArray movArr = resultOBJ.getJSONArray("movies"); 
JSONObject movOBJ =movArr.getJSONObject(0);
String title = movOBJ.getString("title");
String synop = movOBJ.getString("synopsis");

nameView.setText(title);
synopView.setText(synop);
```

the object I receive looks like this (sans formatting):

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "movies": [
        {
            "critics_consensus": "Deftly blending comedy, ...",
            "id": "770672122",
            "mpaa_rating": "G",
            "ratings": {
                "audience_rating": "Upright",
                "audience_score": 87,
                "critics_rating": "Certified Fresh",
                "critics_score": 99
            },
            "release_dates": {
                "dvd": "2010-11-02",
                "theater": "2010-06-18"
            },
            "runtime": 103,
            "title": "Toy Story 3",
            "year": 2010,
            "synopsis": "Pixar returns to their first success with ...
```

et cetra...

Comment: Did you post all Json or only part? because your solution works well

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Wrong text?  Is this constant or only for some movies?

Comment: I posted only part of it.. the result I get from the service is supposedly complete

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/85950/blahdiblah It happens with all movies I try it on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your example (copy/paste), closed some gates for Json ond got proper result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException  {

    String result = "{" + 
            "    \"total\": 1," + 
            "    \"movies\": [" + 
            "        {" + 
            "            \"id\": \"770672122\"," + 
            "            \"title\": \"Toy Story 3\"," + 
            "            \"year\": 2010," + 
            "            \"mpaa_rating\": \"G\"," + 
            "            \"runtime\": 103," + 
            "            \"critics_consensus\": \"Deftly blending comedy,adventure, and honest emotion, Toy Story 3 is a rare second sequel that really works.\"," + 
            "            \"release_dates\": {" + 
            "                \"theater\": \"2010-06-18\"," + 
            "                \"dvd\": \"2010-11-02\"" + 
            "            }," + 
            "            \"ratings\": {" + 
            "                \"critics_rating\": \"Certified Fresh\"," + 
            "                \"critics_score\": 99," + 
            "                \"audience_rating\": \"Upright\"," + 
            "                \"audience_score\": 87" + 
            "            }," + 
            "            \"synopsis\": \"Pixar returns to their first success with Toy Story 3. The movie begins with Andy leaving for college and donating his beloved toys -- including Woody (Tom Hanks) and Buzz (Tim Allen) -- to a daycare. While the crew meets new friends, including Ken (Michael Keaton), they soon grow to hate their new surroundings and plan an escape. The film was directed by Lee Unkrich from a script co-authored by Little Miss Sunshine scribe Michael Arndt. ~ Perry Seibert, Rovi\"" + 
            "        }" + 
            "    ]" + 
            "}";


    JSONObject resultOBJ = new JSONObject(result);

    JSONArray movArr = resultOBJ.getJSONArray("movies"); 

    JSONObject movOBJ =movArr.getJSONObject(0);
    String title = movOBJ.getString("title");
    String synop = movOBJ.getString("synopsis");
    System.out.println(synop); 
}
```

Output:

> Pixar returns to their first success with Toy Story 3. The movie begins with Andy leaving for college and donating his beloved toys -- including Woody (Tom Hanks) and Buzz (Tim Allen) -- to a daycare. While the crew meets new friends, including Ken (Michael Keaton), they soon grow to hate their new surroundings and plan an escape. The film was directed by Lee Unkrich from a script co-authored by Little Miss Sunshine scribe Michael Arndt. ~ Perry Seibert, Rovi

Comment: So could this be connected to the way I build my string?